# Tortoisesvn skips recording mergeinfo

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn, svn-mergeinfo

I have checked out the trunk from one of our svn repos.

I then right click -> merge -> merge some revisions -> merge from branch A -> choose one revision and then finally apply the merge.

My TortoiseSVN updates the files, and updates the mergeinfo.
When I commit these changes to trunk, tortoisesvn shows me the files to commit, and also the /trunk folder which is affected because the svn:mergeinfo has been updated.

My colleague has the exact same tortoisesvn installed, and does exactly the same thing. We have the exact same global ignore pattern. When he does the merge procedure, the svn:mergeinfo property on the trunk won't update. Only the files is merged. How is that possible? Is there a setting which tells tortoisesvn not to include mergeinfo when merging?

Comment: Do both you and your colleague have the same version of Tortoise?  If so, what version is it?

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.8.8, Build 25755 - 64 Bit , 2014/08/10 14:44:06
Subversion 1.8.10, -release
apr 1.5.1
apr-util 1.5.3
serf 1.3.7
OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
zlib 1.2.8

Comment: we both have the same version

Comment: There is checkbox in the merge dialog with the label "Ignore ancestry". It must not be checked.

Comment: TomWolk you saved my day... month :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, this was awkward.
If you do the merge and the URL to merge from has a different base URL than your working copy's checkout URL, the merge will perform, but no mergeinfo is recorded.

The difference in the URL string was a capital letter(!). So this means that the URL to merge from must be exactly equal to your trunk, also the casing of letters.

This must be a bug in tortoiseSVN?

Example:
Checked out trunk from http://****/svn/repo/trunk
Try to merge from url http://****/svn/Repo/branches/****

This will do the merge, but not record mergeinfo

Comment: When I try that in both the Tortoise and the command line client I get an error: "_svn: E195012: 'http://server/Repo/trunk' must be from the same repository as 'workingcopy`_".  Are you sure that's the problem?  If you can reproduce it (ideally in a script), both the Tortoise and SVN devs would likely be keen on seeing it.

Comment: I reproduce it here on my machine and another machine. I don't know how to reproduce it in a script, haven't tried commandline merge, only tortoisesvn.

Comment: i have posted a thread in tortoisesvn community tortoisesvn.tigris.org titled "not recording mergeinfo"

Comment: I have found we have the same problem after moving our SVN server ... however, the repo path shown in the working copy, and the remote one, is identical; no case issue in our case.

Answer (score 0):

There is checkbox in the merge dialog with the label "Ignore ancestry". It must not be checked!

This comment of @TomWolk solved the problem for me.

Comment: Which answert of @TomWolk?

Comment: It is a comment of  @TomWolk for the first question.