# Tortoise 1.9: Merge does not record mergeinfo

Tags: svn, merge, version, mergeinfo

I'm using Tortoise 1.9 as a SVN-client for a Apache Subversion Server 1.7.
I realize that none of my merges are recorded to svn:mergeinfo. Neither "svn mergeinfo --show-revs" nor the Tortoise property-display show the merged revisions.
Merges of other developers (not all of them) are recorded. It seems that the same developers always maintain svn:merginfo and others never maintain this.

I´m not sure, whether this is a problem of the version of the client compared to the servers version. I have searched several articles dealing with the same - but did not find any explanation for this. Is there something I can do to debug/trace this?

Comment: The error looks very similiar to this one "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318180/tortoisesvn-skips-recording-mergeinfo?rq=1"

Comment: Installed me on a openSuse Linux under VirtualBox a Subversion Server 1.9.5 and tested merging with my current Tortoise 1.9.4.

Comment: At least I can say that this works - merginfo is maintained and can be retrieved as descibed in the docs. Need to get me a version 1.7 server to doublecheck with this.
But I can take it probably for sure now, that Tortoise 1.9.4 does not work with the old Apache Subversion 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. And whats worse, the answer was given inf the link I had referenced myself. But hat overlooked it:

So the answer is: "**Ignore ancestry**" must not be checked when doing the merge. Otherwise the svn:mergeinfo will not be maintained.